# Ho to reuse(iterate) code without event triggers

Tags: javascript

Can anybody explain as simple as posible (learning js very slow because of lack of time) how to iterate same piece of code. I need to replay sound again and again after a short delay, using Math.Random without using event triggers.

```
var birdsSing = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
    if ( birdsSing === 1){
        birds.play();
    }
```

Comment: take a look at `setInterval` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setInterval();`

**See:** [JavaScript timers (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `setInterval()` function:

```
// Milliseconds between sound playbacks
// Change this value to how often you want the sound to play
var playbackInterval = 500;

setInterval(function() {
    var birdsSing = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
    if (birdsSing === 1) { birds.play(); }
}, playbackInterval);
```